# Why does"toMatchInlineSnapshot" is getting empty content even if the component simply return some content?

Tags: reactjs, tdd

After few days of wondering I finally decided to ask here why it is happenning something very strange for me. I am not yet able to run my first and complete test series with react. I got a lot of difficulties. It is very hard to me start testing with React18. I am also new to React. I love to test since years and years in PHPUnit context. Mainly in unit tests. So, .. I think my approach here could be quite wrong if nothing works. Here is my test:

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import { unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom"
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils"
import pretty from "pretty"

const Hello = () => {
    render(
        <div data-testid="prova">Hi, Stranger!</div>
    )
};

let container = null;

beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement("div")
    document.body.appendChild(container)
});

afterEach(() => {
    unmountComponentAtNode(container)
    container.remove()
    container = null
});

describe(Hello, () => {
    it("should render a greeting", () => {
        act(() => { render(<Hello />, container) })
        expect(pretty(container.innerHTML)).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"Hi, Stranger!"`)
    })
})
```

And here there is my output

[image]

What I expected was that `expect(pretty(container.innerHTML)).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"Hi, Stranger!"`)` did work. But for a reason I do not understand. It didnt. So. There is something wrong with component rendering?